# Netflix Turbine standalone war configuration

Tags: netflix, turbine

I am trying to configure Hystrix monitoring with Turbine aggregator.
I have successfully exposed Hystrix stream.

I would like to inject custom configuration into turbine war so I downloaded turbine-web-1.0.0.war and put into archive WEB-INF/config.properties with following content:

```
turbine.ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery.default.instances=127.0.1.1
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix=:8080/testapp/hystrix.stream
```

When I start Turbine aggregator it logs following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://<instance1b>:80/hystrix.stream
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:69)
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor.init(InstanceMonitor.java:305)
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor.access$100(InstanceMonitor.java:103)
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor$2.call(InstanceMonitor.java:235)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://<instance1b>:80/hystrix.stream
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3186)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I have no idea where instance1b comes from as my configuration doesn't contain anything like this.

If this is not correct what would be correct approach to use standalone turbine war.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to store it at WEB-INF/classes/config.properties. Its still picking default file at WEB-INF/classes/config.properties, hence throwing such error.